# piece._page._url nor working after adding projection

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have a widget where I can handpick links to other pages on the site.
In **focuslinks-widgets/views/widget.html**:

```
{% for piece in data.widget._pieces %}
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <a href="{{ piece._page._url }}" class="button">{{ piece.title }}</a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

My **focuslinks/index.js**

```
module.exports = {
    extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
    name: 'focuslink',
    label: 'Fokuslink',
    pluralLabel: 'Fokuslinker',
    addFields: [
        {
            name: 'title',
            label: 'Navn',
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        {
            name: '_page',
            type: 'joinByOne',
            withType: 'apostrophe-page',
            label: 'Side',
            required: true,
            idField: 'pageId'
        }
    ]
};
```

This was working as intended, but I had another problem resulting in slow page multiple warnings about missing projections. So for the above widget, I added projections in **app.js**:

```
'supernode-focuslinks': {},
'supernode-focuslinks-widgets': {
    extend: 'apostrophe-pieces-widgets',
    filters: {
        projection: {
            slug: 1,
            title: 1,
            type: 1,
            tags: 1
        }
    }
},
```

Now after this the widget is displaying as before, but there are no href url generated by *{{ piece._page._url }}* anymore. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The projection you've written here fetches enough information to set the `_url` property of the piece itself, but not of the page it's joining with (`.piece._page._url`). To do that you're going to have to make sure your projection also includes the page id so that it can be joined.

That would look like:

```
projection: {
  title: 1,
  _url: 1,
  _page: 1
}
```

With this shorthand, using the name of the join itself, Apostrophe looks up the name of the idField for you. Similarly, if you specify `_url: 1` Apostrophe substitutes the usual suspects needed to calculate that for a piece or page.

You should also add a projection to the `_page` join itself. You don't want to pay the overhead of loading every image and who knows what else on the page just to make a link to it. That is probably what is causing the system to look back and load things more than once, resulting in the warnings you saw.

Comment: Adding _url and _page brought me back to the initial state/problem, but adding a projection to the _page join solved it. I think maybe the documentation could use some more explanation/clarification ;)

Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `_url: 1` to your projection object

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made